# Ascii encoding with french characters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a small method that send request to remote database and we use these two lines:

```
var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(jsonRequest);
using (var newStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

when I send the request direct using a test portal, french characters are saved correctly and retrieved correctly, and when sent using our application the server reads them as ? (here french characters are éà etc...)
I have tried to debug the application and found that the data(jsonRequest) is valid at the point of    byte[] data.

I am asking is it possible that the encoding is making the character distort? ofcourse this being someone else's code with no explanation as to why this was done I have little options.
any help is appreciated.

Ta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is likely the encoding you are using. ASCII was originated in the US, and doesn't include European accents. What happens if you don't use any encoding? I've never had to add any character encoding for JSON requests. If I did have to choose and encoding, utf-8 would be the best.

Are your servers and web pages configured to use utf-8?

Comment: hi they are but this is a low level communication(application send data from a webpage but this is done via other projects(Class project for data transmission)).Anyway thanks I used the UTF8Encoding() instead and now it is working perfectly hence I am marking your response as the answer

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this before.  In our case it was because, even though the chracters were sent correctly from the server, it sent the resolved version - effectively, they lost the encoding.  So we had a secondary function on the client side in JS, to encode the chracters again before HTML rendered them.

Comment: @durbnpoison I don't understand what you did there? sorry can you be more clear please? not sure I understand what I can do to resolve it